# Find the least non negative residues mod 7,11 and 13 of 12345678.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the least non negative residues mod 7,11 and 13 of 12345678.

**my attempt:** A number N is congruent modulo 7, 11, or 13, to the alternating sum of its digits in base 1000. (For example, 123456789 ≡ 789 − 456 + 123 ≡ 456 mod 7, 11, or 13.)

Comment: So you are almost done, What is your question?

Comment: @BillDubuque.. i didt get answer for 12345678

Comment: You don't know how to reduce $456$ for the moduli $7,11,13?\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque.. my number is 12345678

Comment: @BillDubuque..how can we express 12345678

Comment: It works the same way. Append some leading zeroes if you like, e.g  $\  1002 = 2-1 = 1,\ $ or $\ 001002 = 002 - 001 = 1\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque.. i am confusing can right it expresiion

Comment: @BillDubuque..not understand

Comment: We are taking the alternating sum of the digits in radix $1000$. The digits of $\,12,345,678\,$ are those chunks of $3$ delineated by the commas.Their alternating sum is $\,678 - 345 + 12\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque..678-543+012 is it right

Comment: @BillDubuque..thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What  I can do if I have understood well the question is the clear

$$12345678=949667\cdot13+\color{red}7=1122334\cdot11+\color{red}4=1763668\cdot7+\color{red}2$$ where the asked residues are in red.